# use intro image in related articles module for Jooma 3.4

Tags: image, module, joomla3.0, related-content

I would like to get the intro images to show in the related articles module. I've made an override /my template/html/mod_related_items/default.php but I can't find a code that works.
Ideally I would love to have the related items displayed in like a 4 x 2 articles (not as a list) and with the intro image and title clicable.

I'm a newbie, please help :-)
You can find my webpage here if that will help.

https://www.grønne-unger.dk/aftensmad/gryderetter/17-borne-dahl

Thanks in advance :-)

Answer (score 0):

sql query of mod_related_items isn't loading image field. 
so you have to write your own query inside mod_related_items/default.php and fetch image from #__content by article id.

try var_dump($item) inside given foreach at default.php to have a look what is getting loaded & what need to be loaded.